# image processing using c++

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

**anyone can help me in this please.**

i am trying to implement a C++ application related to color in the general sense. the project is composed of a common set of tasks upon which you can propose two different types application. the common functionalities of the project can be summarized as follow:
pixelise an image, which requires"
- the ability to load and display an image located anywhere on your hard drive and to save any processed image.
- the provided software should allow to transform the loaded image into the second one such that the pixels' color of the second image is computed according to various methods (average, median, most represented color, etc.) so that image is pixelised.

i tried this and dont know where am i going with this.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
     Mat img = imread("MyPic.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); //read the image data in the file "MyPic.JPG" and store it in 'img'

     if (img.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
     {
          cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
          //system("pause"); //wait for a key press
          return -1;
     }

     namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
     imshow("MyWindow", img); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

     waitKey(0); //wait infinite time for a keypress

     destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting project, but it's not a very specific problem. Do you have any **code** which isn't working as expected?

Comment: I don't see a question here...

Comment: now you see? @Vilx

Comment: Nop, still no question marks. :) Also, "help me please" is a pretty useless thing to ask. That's like asking others to do it for you. (Hint: we won't). Try to solve it yourself and ask specific questions about things you get stuck on.

Comment: As far as I know the library you are using does all that stuff for you, just read the documentation and use it accordingly. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html

Comment: Just a warning about averaging color in pixels. RGB values are typically scaled as an exponential. Make sure you convert to a linear space before doing the math then convert back to the normal, exponential space.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd suggest you try Qt as QImage object handles some common images formats (jpeg, bmp, png, and some others) and allows most of your requirements with few effort. Loading, viewing and saving an image is made quite easely. Color transformation is also possible (but needs more efforts, and maybe not with the best possible performance), that can be a good start.

Comment: Easy to downvote, especially without comments.